# Fill Handle but for Data Validation?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So what I'm trying to do is make a Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List without Using Apps Scripts.

What I want to do is, Much like using the Fill Handle to select and copy a formula in a cell to other cells while changing the refrences where appropriate, I want to do that but with Data Validation Like:
`B2` has a Dropdown from Range `E2:2`
`B3` has a Dropdown from Range `E3:3`
`B4` has a Dropdown from Range `E4:4`
`B5` has a Dropdown from Range `E5:5` etc...

[image]

the data validation rule:
[image]

I don't mind using Apps Scripts to setup the Data Validation as long as it's only for the setup and not required to keep it functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole range B2:B, and apply the data validation range without the "$" symbols. Apply it and check. Sometimes, the "$" symbols are automatically added (meaning it still doesn't do what you expect): just select again the whole range and edit the previous data validation removing the $ symbols and it should work!

[image]

[image]

[image]